# Simple Web app with Jersey returns 404

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to implement a very simple web app with Jersey- server side. I am not using Maven or eclipse or any other tool. I call the url below:

http://server:port/RestfulExample/hello

I keep track of Log file, this is what I see:

GET /RestfulExample/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 5

I looked at many other posts, I tried to make sure my url pattern is matching with what I have in main.java, web.xml and the url I call.
I was originally following vogella's tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html).

main.java class:

```
package com.unitask.web;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")

public class main{

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String sayPlainTextHello(){
      return "Hello Jersey";
   }//end of hello

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}//end of class
```

web.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">

  <display-name>Restful Application Example</display-name>
      <description>
          Restful Server App Sample using Jersey.
      </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web App</servlet-name>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.unitask.web.main</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web App</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

Comment: Isn't any other error message in the log apart of the 404?

Comment: Actually there is, I just found out in catalina.out:: SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 2 column 6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is                             not allowed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/RestfulExample/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 2; col                            umnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
I don't understand though, my web.xml looks correct to me

Comment: There was an empty line at the beginning of my web.xml. I got rid of that line. It doesn't throw any errors any more.But HTTP code turned to 503. @Luiggi Mendoza thanks for pointing out the error messages.

Comment: Well, since it throws a 503, probably you should comment one of the methods since there are two endpoints for the same URL.

Comment: I realized that my WEB-INF/lib directory hierarchy was incorrect. I unzipped the jersey distribution and I had this: WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-ri. I set it correctly in my compile script but I didn't realize it wouldn't work when I deploy it. Anyway..It's working now. Thanks for the help @Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: I wonder why don't you use an IDE to ease this :)

Comment: I think my boss likes watching me suffer, I don't know =)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have two method mappings for single `@Path("/hello")` pattern. So it is ambiguous.

Map each method to a different URL pattern using @Path. like

```
@Path("/hello")
public class main{

   @Path("/sayPlain")
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String sayPlainTextHello(){
      return "Hello Jersey";
   }//end of hello


  @Path("/sayHTML")
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}//end of class
```

Comment: I added 
   @Path("/plainHello") to the plain method and  @Path("/htmlHello") to the second one. I called following URLs: http://server:port:18081/RestfulExample/hello/plainHello and http://server:port:18081/RestfulExample/plainHello. It still returns 404